# Is there a way to conditionally copy a file using ant?

Tags: java, ant

I have the following target:

```
<target name="promptforchoice">

  <input addproperty="choice">
     Copy the file?.  [Y, n]
  </input>

    <condition property="copy.file">
        <or>
            <equals arg1="Y" arg2="${choice}"/>
            <equals arg1="y" arg2="${choice}"/>
        </or>
    </condition>

</target>
```

In another target, I'd like to conditionally copy a file depending on whether or not the copy.file property is set. **Is this possible?** Is there some other way to accomplish it?

---

### My Solution

Here's what I came up with based on [ChrisH's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433975/is-there-a-way-to-conditionally-copy-a-file-using-ant/2434005#2434005).

```
<target name="promptforchoice">

  <input addproperty="choice">
     Copy the file?.  [Y, n]
  </input>

    <condition property="copy.file">
        <or>
            <equals arg1="Y" arg2="${choice}"/>
            <equals arg1="y" arg2="${choice}"/>
        </or>
    </condition>

</target>

<target name="copyfile" if="copy.file">
    <copy file="file1.cfg" tofile="file2.cfg"/>
</target>

<target name="build" depends="promptforchoice">
    <antcall target="copyfile"/>

    <!--  Other stuff goes here -->

</target>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
<target name="mycopy" if="copy.file">
   <!-- do copy -->
</target>
```